# Insert columns only once when i first execute the macro and not again if i run the macro second/third time etc

Tags: vba, excel

please can you help me with my VBA problem?  I would like the macro to insert 4 columns starting in column C, and then name each column as below.  However, each time i execute the macro it keeps adding 4 columns, or repeating the command, how do i stop this?  The columns should only be inserted on the first execution and not afterwards.  Many thanks in advance.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Range("C:F").EntireColumn.Insert
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Range("C1").Value = "Factor"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Range("D1").Value = "Materials"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Range("E1").Value = "Labour"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Range("F1").Value = "Overheads"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Columns("A:I").AutoFit
```

Comment: Thank you,  does exactly what it says on the tin. Brill!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this

Option Explicit

```
Sub main()
Dim headings As Variant

headings = Array("Factor", "Materials", "Labour", "Overheads")

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C")
    If Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range("C1:F1").value)), "|") <> Join(headings, "|") Then
        .Range("C:F").EntireColumn.Insert
        .Range("C1:F1").value = headings
    End If
    .Columns("A:I").AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

it checks for ALL headings to be in place in order to "act".

I also argued that `.Autofit` would always have to run

adapt it to your actual needs

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the code you have in an if statement. This is untested, but it should look something like this:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Range("C1").Value <> "Factor" Then
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Range("C:F").EntireColumn.Insert
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Range("C1").Value = "Factor"
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Range("D1").Value = "Materials"
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Range("E1").Value = "Labour"
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Range("F1").Value = "Overheads"
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAPZK67C").Columns("A:I").AutoFit
End if
```

Comment: Edited my answer as some VBA syntax came back to me

Comment: @Zakky Edited to use not equal operator